Run local tests with the same configuration
I have a maven-based project. Some tests are in spock, others in JUnit. Imagine a project with legacy tests, which migration is still in-progress.
Maven is set to run the tests with groovy (spock) mocks activated only in case of a groovy file, whereas for JUnit tests spock tests are deactivated, in order to not interfere with its own mocks (mockito/mockk or whathever). Everything works fine if executed by maven. The key is passing as an argLine the proper value -Dspock-mockable.disabled=true/false
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-unit-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                            <argLine>-Dspock-mockable.disabled=true</argLine>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*UnitTest.kt</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*.groovy</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-kt-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                            <argLine>-Dspock-mockable.disabled=true</argLine>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.kt</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*.groovy</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-spock-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                            <argLine>-Dspock-mockable.disabled=false</argLine>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*.kt</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

The problem: if running as a single test/class test from IntelliJ, the test runner does not evaluate the include/exclude rules, and the variable is not set by default.
I should "Modify run configuration" each time I touch a groovy test, in order to add it as an argument, which is cumbersome.

I'm trying to find a way to make it work with zero configuration (or just a one-shot setup) and let the IDE pass the variable to true/false according to the type of test.
What I can do is creating a run configuration, but for running all the spock or Junit tests. I just want running a single one, or at most a class, from the IDE.

That looks like a potential limitation of IDEA's Testing Subsystem or of the way it digests Maven configuration.
Might be worth posting this on IDEA's YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with a reproducer Project, so the developers can look into this.
